# Javascript - Giving the wrong status Code during tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I am running tests for signin controller, it keeps giving the wrong status code (401) instead of 200 as i programmed it to be.
I expect it to use the data stored when a user signs up and return it if the given input is correct.
It works perfectly in postman but as i am writing tests, it throws the 401 error.
It is like it does not find the user

This is test block for the sign in:

```
it('it should signin a new user', (done) => {
      request(app)
      .post('/api/users/signin')
      .send({
        username: "Charles",        
        password: "challenger",               
      })
      .expect(200)
      .end((err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          return done(err);
        }        

        done()
      });
    });
```

This is my controller for Logging in:

```
signin(req, res) {

    const username = req.body.username.toLowerCase().trim();
    // const email = req.body.email.trim();

    if(!username) {
      return res.status(401)
      .send(
        {status: false, 
          message: "Username cannot be empty"
        });
    } 
    else if (!req.body.password) {
      return res.status(401)
      .send({
        status: false,
        message: "Password field cannot be empty"
        });
    }
    return User.findOne({
      where: {
        username,
      }
    })
    .then((user) =>{     

      if(!user) {
        return res.status(401).send({message: "User is not registered"})
      }
      else if(!user.validPassword(req.body.password)){
        return res.status(401)
        .send({
          message: "The password is incorrect"
        })
      }
      const token = user.generateAuthToken();
      res.header('x-auth', token).status(200).send({
      statusCode: 200,
      message: `Welcome back, ${user.username}`,
      user
    });
    })
    .catch(error => {return res.status(400).send(error)})
  },
```

This is the error i get:

```
1) Testing API routes POST /api/users/ it should signin a new user:
     Error: expected 200 "OK", got 401 "Unauthorized"
      at Test._assertStatus (node_modules\supertest\lib\test.js:266:12)
      at Test._assertFunction (node_modules\supertest\lib\test.js:281:11)
      at Test.assert (node_modules\supertest\lib\test.js:171:18)
      at Server.assert (node_modules\supertest\lib\test.js:131:12)
      at emitCloseNT (net.js:1552:8)
      at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:11)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

Comment: The 400 is caused by a javascript error somewhere in the last then() clause.Try outputting the value of "error" in your catch block at the end, that will tell you what failed.

Comment: @DuncanThacker sorry it gives a 401 error not a 400 error. The user can sign in well on postman but my test still fails. The error happens if there is no user

Comment: Which message does it send with the 401? That should help figure out which bit of the code is going wrong.

Comment: Also might be worth checking that the user you're setting up the user correctly before the tests starts.

Comment: @DuncanThacker just updated it with the error, anytime i run the tests, a user is signed up and i see it in the database

Comment: @letmebe I'd check whether there's something executing *before* your code that prevents the request from even reaching your code. Security middleware, for instance, may reject a request before your code sees it.

Comment: @Louis there is no middleware, what can i do?

Comment: @Louis there is no middleware, what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

I would put a bunch of `console.log()` in there to see exactly which code is firing since you have 4 chances to fire the 401.

Here is some code for you to examine:

```
// I don't understand enough context, so I have to re-write this
// to show you how it could be an async function which will
// return a promise, but will also allow you to await.

// async function sign(req, res) {
const sign = async (req, res) => { // This is same as above line

    const username = req.body.username.toLowerCase().trim();
    // const email = req.body.email.trim();

    if (!username) {
        console.log('username was empty')
        return res.status(401).send({
            status: false, 
            message: "Username cannot be empty"
        });
    } 

    if (!req.body.password) {
        console.log('password was empty')
        return res.status(401).send({
            status: false,
            message: "Password field cannot be empty"
        });
    }

    return await User.findOne({ where: { username } })
        // I'm making this one async also to ensure user.generateAuthToken()
        // has a value before it proceeds to res.send()
        .then(async (user) => {     
            if (!user) {
                console.log('couldnt find user')
                return res.status(401).send({
                    message: "User is not registered"
                })
            }

            else if (!user.validPassword(req.body.password)){
                console.log('password was incorrect')
                return res.status(401).send({
                    message: "The password is incorrect"
                })
            }

            const token = await user.generateAuthToken();
            // I added a return here
            return res.header('x-auth', token).status(200).send({
                statusCode: 200,
                message: `Welcome back, ${user.username}`,
                user
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('lets put data in here: ' + error)
            return res.status(400).send(error)
        })
},
```

> I notice the MongoDB search `User.findOne({ where: { username } })`. I can't remember if it needs to be `$where`. I think MongoDB syntax uses a $. That could be your problem, and it will fire that `console.log('couldnt find user')` if so. That might be only for native MongoDB driver. I just Googled and found that the syntax could also be: `User.findOne({ username })` which is shorthand for `User.findOne({ username: username })`.

Some people will tell you it is redundant to do `return await fn()` and omit the `await`, but it will throw an unhandled promise rejection if the promise is rejected. It will be caught if await is there. This is part of the upper scope's error handling architecture.

I recommend watching some async/await tutorials, because I see you mixing in a little bit of callback sauce. Your code is pretty good, but I think you can take it to the next level. It looks like you're ready.

Fun fact, you can also omit `{` and `}` if your `if` statement only has one expression, ie:

```
if (err) {
    throw err;
}
```

can be shorthand:

```
if (err) throw err;
```

This can go a long way to help clean up the code, but async/await syntax with try/catch blocks used properly along with `throw` will do incredible improvements to synchronous looking code with minimal nesting.

Here is how you could re-write some of this, because I want to show you how we can get rid of nesting that adds confusion to your flow control:

```
const sign = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const username = req.body.username.toLowerCase().trim()
        if (!username) throw 'noUsername'
        if (!req.body.password) throw 'noPassword'

        const foundUser = await User.findOne({ username })
        if (!foundUser.username) throw 'notFound'

        // I assume this returns Boolean
        const validPassword = await user.validPassword(req.body.password)
        if (!validPassword) throw 'invalidPassword'

        // Alter generateAuthToken() to throw 'badToken' if it fails
        const token = await user.generateAuthToken()
        return res.header('x-auth', token).status(200).send({
            statusCode: 200,
            message: `Welcome back, ${user.username}`,
            user
        })
    } catch (error) {
        // errors are manually thrown into here, and rejected promises
        // are automatically thrown into here
        if (error === 'noUsername') return res.status(401).send({
            status: false, 
            message: 'Username cannot be empty'
        })

        if (error === 'noPassword') return res.status(401).send({
            status: false,
            message: 'Password field cannot be empty'
        })

        if (error === 'notFound') return res.status(401).send({
            message: 'User is not registered'
        })

        if (error === 'invalidPassword') return res.status(401).send({
            message: 'The password is incorrect'
        })

        if (error === 'badToken') return res.status(403).send({
            message: 'User is not authorized'
        })

        return res.status(400).send(error)
    }
}

sign(req, res).then((response) => console.log(response))
```

Hopefully, this has been helpful :) and sorry I don't use semi-colons.